# VBA How to return null from a function

Tags: excel, vba, null

I have this function

```
Public Function parseEmployee(ByVal employeeId As Integer, _ 
                              ByVal ws As Worksheet) As employee
    Dim emp As New employee
    Dim empRow As Range
    If sheetContainsEmployee(employeeId, ws) Then
        Set empRow = ws.Rows(ws.Columns(ID_COLUMN).Find(employeeId).Row)
        emp.id = employeeId
        emp.Name = empRow.Cells(1, NAME_COLUMN).Value
    Else
        emp = Null ' Heres what I'd like to do
    End If

    parseEmployee = emp
End Function
```

And I'd like to return null in case that the employee is not found in the sheet, is that possible? I get an object or variable nblock not set. error

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Only a `Variant` can be `Null`, instead use `Nothing`:

```
Public Function parseEmployee(ByVal employeeId As Integer, _  
                              ByVal ws As Worksheet) As employee 
    Dim emp As New employee 
    Dim empRow As Range 
    If sheetContainsEmployee(employeeId, ws) Then 
        Set empRow = ws.Rows(ws.Columns(ID_COLUMN).Find(employeeId).Row) 
        emp.id = employeeId 
        emp.Name = empRow.Cells(1, NAME_COLUMN).Value 
    Else 
        Set emp = Nothing
    End If 

    Set parseEmployee = emp
End Function
```

The way you would test:

```
  Dim emp As employee 
  Set emp = parseEmployee( ... )

  If emp Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print "No employee returned."
  End If
```

Ref: [Nothing? Empty? Missing? Null?](http://allenbrowne.com/vba-NothingEmpty.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried setting it to nothing but I still get the Run-time error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set.

Comment: You need `Set emp = Nothing` Also add the Set on the "return" line.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that returning Nothing from a function causes an exception.

What I did instead was to write a sub that takes a ByRef parameter that is your return value.

Instead of this:

```
Public Function test() as SomeClass
     set test = Nothing
End Function
```

I wrote this:

```
Public Sub test(ByRef result as SomeClass)
     result = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

just use """", or "", which one will work, you could try, as:

Else 
        Set emp = """"

note that there is no space between